# How do I just SAVE a jsFiddle and not get a new version

Tags: jsfiddle

In the documentation:

Buttons Save or Fork are always present in the UI. First one appears if no fiddle was loaded, the latter is used to create a new fiddle from the existing one.

I ONLY see SAVE when the fiddle is brand new, then RUN/update/fork. In Fx4 and Safari 5 on MAC (and Fx 4 on pc)

[image]

UPDATE: New BASE functionality does exactly what I wanted.

[image: New version]

From the [SO FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)

> Stack Overflow is for professional and
>   enthusiast programmers, people who
>   write code because they love it. We
>   feel the best Stack Overflow questions
>   have a bit of source code in them, but
>   if your question generally covers …
>
> - a specific programming problem
> - a software algorithm
> - **software tools commonly used by programmers**
> - matters that are unique to the programming profession
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Comment: WHERE can I ask this so it is not closed??? SHEEZ! From the FAQ _software tools commonly used by programmers_

Comment: This one would go to WebApps I guess. It is now being closed to Super User though

Comment: I really hate their interface.

Comment: Great system but this is one thing that seems like the developer got too cute about - just have a simple save button.  I lost a day of work because I thought update acted as a save button.

Comment: They normally have a "you have unsaved drafts" and update does work as a save - you just need to remember the number if you no longer have the update link but only the base link

Answer (score 66, accepted):

When you log into JsFiddle, you'll get a **Set as Base** button, which will make the revision you're working on the base version - think of it as an alias for **john/7hd62/12/** -> **john/7hd62/**.

Comment: Yeah, NOW I can. It is excellent. It was not available when I asked the question

Comment: Well the functionality has been there for a year (or more) now. You just had to log-in.

Comment: where did all revisions go...this means ive been using jsfiddle wrong...for every different concept i should be using fork, and revisions not as place holders for experimenting different things this way...ugh i wish i could further nest jsfiddles into groups.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer Revisions didn't go anywhere. You can access them manually.

Comment: by manually you mean you need to have link to it, right.. Because within jsfiddle.com i can't find any previous versions. Though, as you said links to them still work.

Comment: If you create a fiddle, then log in, you have to Fork your fiddle to get the Set as Base button.

Answer (score 18):

I ran into an issue where set as base would not save my work. The solution was to:

- make a change.
- Update to get a new version.
- Set as Base.

Hope that helps

Comment: wow this worked!  why was that so confusing.  i would navigate back to my fiddle again and again and apply draft changes and then set as base and it would never work as i wanted.

Answer (score 2):

I always use Update to save and create a new revision.

I haven't seen the button Save... maybe it is so that we can't Save to a version, but always need to Update to a new version, so everybody can look at the same code at a certain version.

Comment: @動靜能量: How to save a fiddle with a name ?

Comment: Add a title to publish - there does not seem to be a way to give it a name. It would be difficult to handle duplicates

Comment: This answer is useful because it points out that there's no Save button, as the only way to save is to create a new version. That's intuitive, but what's not intuitive is the fact that URLs keep pointing to the old versions by default. What's missing from this answer is that you can share the generic URL instead, as long as you manually use the Base button every single time you save--erm, update--to a new version.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on [Issue #225 in JSFiddle GitHub Repository - URL for the latest version of a fiddle such as /xxxxx/latest/](https://github.com/jsfiddle/jsfiddle-issues/issues/225):

> @zalun: Please read http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#setting-base-version
>   Sharing a latest fiddle is not always what you wanted. Because anyone is able to save "latest" fiddle, someone would be able to change it to the content you wouldn't like to share. With setting a base version you are the person who chooses which version is shared under default "no version" URL.